# What language or platform is used to develop apps for Google+?

Tags: web, social

Does anyone know what language or platform is used to develop apps for Google+?

I'm hoping Python, but I know google has a lot of other mediums they could use for this. I'm fine with hearsay as I know the game portion of google+ is pretty new.

Answer (score 12):

App development for Google+ looks to be similar to app development for Facebook.  That is to say, you will likely be able to use any language or platform that allows the game to be played in a browser, and you will interface with the API via RESTful style requests (basically making an HTTP call to something like api.plus.google.com)

My guess is that this will mostly translate to a lot of people using Flash, Unity, and HTML5/Javascript.

To add more to this, since I can now check what various games are using: Angry Birds is using HTML5/Javascript (most likely the same one they're using for Google Chrome's app store).  City of Wonder is using Flash.  Those are the only games I really bothered looking at, but it's enough proof that multiple languages are possible.

Comment: Yea, I've been addicted to Edge World and it's flash. For whatever reason, it won't let you type in the chat box while maximized, but I think the message comes directly from Flash. On a side note, I hope we can use something more robust than flash or javascript + html 5. The chrome version of angry birds is pretty wonky. Just MHO.

Answer (score 1):

Purely speculation here but...

The Google App Engine supports Python, Java and Go for site development.  It wouldn't be unreasonable to suggest Google will give all three GAE languages the right hooks for Google+ application development.

My current approach is to use GAE and Users Python API, since to use a Google+ app you will have to authenticate with a Google account.